# VB.Net Timer Tick

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have a few usercontrols that have timers on them (I've removed all but one to see if that was the issue), they are enabled and set to 1000ms intervals. The issue I am having is that each of the subs that I am calling within the timer are firing 5 times in a row before starting the count over. I even removed the If statements set the Timer interval to 60000 and only called one Sub. The problem still persisted.

Any help would be appreciated!

Interval set to 1000

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static j As Integer
    Static i As Integer

    '1 min Timer
    If i >= 60 Then
        popupmsg()
        i = 0
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If

    '15 Sec Timer
    If j >= 15 Then
        UpdateGrid()
        j = 0
    Else
        j = j + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Interval set to 60000

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    popupmsg()
End Sub
```

Update with Sub Called

```
Public Sub popupmsg()
    Dim dt As DataTable = Tbl_Mod_HaulerLoadsTableAdapter1.GetDataBy_spGetLastInsertedRowFromTbl_Mod_HaulerLoadsbyAssetID(iAssetID)
    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
    Else
        HaulerLoadID = dt.Rows(0).Item("HaulerLoadsID")
        If iHaulsCount = 0 Then
            iHaulsCount = HaulerLoadID
        Else
            If iHaulsCount < HaulerLoadID Then
                If dt.Rows(0).Item("HaulerLoadsDispatched").ToString = "" Then
                    If dt.Rows(0).Item("HaulerLoadsLogOperator").ToString <> UserID Then
                        If frmMainNew.AcceptHaulAlert = True Then
                            iHaulsCount = HaulerLoadID
                            frmMainNew.AlertControl1.Images = frmMainNew.ImageList2.Images(1)
                            frmMainNew.AlertControl1.Show(frmMainNew, "Hauler", "There is a New Hauler Load Item", frmMainNew.ImageList2.Images(1))
                        End If
                    Else
                    End If
                End If
            Else
            End If
            iHaulsCount = HaulerLoadID
        End If
    End If
    dt.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: What does popupmsg() method do?

Comment: With the if statements removed from the tick event what is the problem? The sub gets called too many times?

Comment: I removed everything except 'i = i + 1' and it take 4 loops (ticks) for 'i' to change from 0 to 1, four more loops for it to change from 1 to 2 and so on. I've renamed 'i' to a completely unique name to make sure its not a overlap of another variable.

Comment: It holds that value for the four loops too, so it causes the Sub to fire four times in a row.

Comment: A single tick event with a static int will count normally without needing 4 ticks to get from 0 to 1. There must be something else you've not shown in your program. Are you using threading?

Comment: That's my confusion, I'm not using any threading and no other code should be affecting the timer. I've even tried to remove the timer and add a new one renaming it with a new name.

Comment: It sounds like the timer is being started multiple times or something. How is it being started?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use static, but Dim.
Static specifies that one or more declared local variables are to continue to exist and retain their latest values after termination of the procedure in which they are declared. 
i and j are initialised to 0 only once.

Comment: Changing it to Dim didnt help, though I stripped the Method down to                                     
                                                                                                         
'Private Sub TimeerHauls_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimeerHauls.Tick
        Static i As Integer
        i = i + 1
    End Sub'                                                                                            
 and it takes 4 loops to change from 0 to 1, 4 more to change i from 1 to 2 and so forth. it take 4 loops to add the +1 for some reason.

Comment: If you're using static, there may be other subs using variables names i and j. Use DIM in the definition section of your form.

Comment: I changed it from Static to Dim, it never gets past 0. It Loops but its not holding that value.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. Everytime the subs is called, the variables are initialised once again. i and j must be preserved for every time the tick is called. Dim statement must be out of the sub.